# Conditional probability - P(A & B|C)P(C)

Tags: probability

I have a question:

$P(A \cap B \cap C)$

$=P(A \cap B|C)P(C)$

$=P(A | B \cap C)P(B|C)P(C)$

Does anyone know why $P(A \cap B|C)P(C) = P(A|B \cap C)P(B|C)P(C)$ ?

I am thinking $P(A \cap B|C)$ should $= P(C|A \cap B)P(A)P(B) / P(C)$ instead of $P(A|B \cap C)P(B|C)$?

This is one of the steps of a prove and I am stuck in here, anyone help ?

Also, may I ask is $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A | B \cap C)P(B)P(C) = P(A \cap B | C)P(C)$?

Thanks!!

Comment: you should tell what you know and what you don't about this introductory section on Probability. For instance can you quickly operate with only A and B ? and the add C?

Answer (score 2):

Conditional probability gives us

\begin{align}
P[A|B] = \frac{P[A\cap B]}{P[B]}
\end{align}

Then

\begin{align}
P[A \cap B | C] = \frac{P[(A \cap B) \cap C]}{P[C]}
\end{align}

So, your first equality follows.

For the second equality, note that

\begin{align}
P[A |B \cap C]P[B|C]P[C] &= \frac{P[A \cap (B \cap C)]}{P[B \cap C]}P[B|C]P[C] \\ &= \frac{P[A \cap (B \cap C)]}{P[B \cap C]}\frac{P[B \cap C]}{P[C]}P[C] \\ &= P[A \cap B \cap C]
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

It is just:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\cap X) ~=~ & \mathsf P(A\mid X)~\mathsf P(X)\\[2ex]\mathsf P(A\cap \color{silver}{(}B\cap C\color{silver}{)}) ~=~& \mathsf P(A\mid B\cap C)~\mathsf P(B\cap C) \\[1ex] ~=~& \mathsf P(A\mid B\cap C)~\mathsf P(B\mid C)~\mathsf P(C)\end{align}$$

Does that make more sense?

And since *also* $\mathsf P(\color{silver}{(}A\cap B\color{silver}{)}\cap C) ~=~ \mathsf P(A\cap B\mid C)~\mathsf P(C)$ we can use the above to see that $$\mathsf P(A\cap B\mid C) ~=~ \mathsf P(A\mid B\cap C)~\mathsf P(B\mid C)$$

Is that clear now?